# problems with installation libtorch

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch

I have done all the requirements, but it doesn't work. My OS is windows, I work on visual studio. I installed CUDA toolkit 12.1, CMake the latest version, and libtorch 12.1 release version. I followed the instructions from the page https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html. I had to download nsight nvtx 11.8, but further wasn't any problems.

```
C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\example-app>mkdir build

C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\example-app>cd build

C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\example-app\build>cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Packages\libtorch ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33134.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33134.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1 (found version "12.1")
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 12.1.66
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/bin/nvcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CUDA compile features
-- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
-- Found CUDAToolkit: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include (found version "12.1.66")
-- Caffe2: CUDA detected: 12.1
-- Caffe2: CUDA nvcc is: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/bin/nvcc.exe
-- Caffe2: CUDA toolkit directory: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1
-- Caffe2: Header version is: 12.1
-- C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64/nvrtc.lib shorthash is bac8224f
-- USE_CUDNN is set to 0. Compiling without cuDNN support
-- USE_CUSPARSELT is set to 0. Compiling without cuSPARSELt support
-- Autodetected CUDA architecture(s):  7.5
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: -gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75
-- Found Torch: C:/Packages/libtorch/lib/torch.lib
-- Configuring done (23.2s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Acer/C++ projects/fraimworks/example-app/build

C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\example-app\build>cmake --build . --config Release
Версия MSBuild 17.8.5+b5265ef37 для .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Acer/C++ projects/fraimworks/example-app/CMakeLists.txt
  example-app.cpp
     Creating library C:/Users/Acer/C++ projects/fraimworks/example-app/build/Release/example-app.lib and object C:/Use
  rs/Acer/C++ projects/fraimworks/example-app/build/Release/example-app.exp
  example-app.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\example-app\build\Release\example-app.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Acer/C++ projects/fraimworks/example-app/CMakeLists.txt
```

C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\example-app\build>

I don't understand why it don't work.I just can't use torch in other projects visual studio.I try #include torch but it prints :`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'torch': No such file or directory Project1 C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\Project1\main.cpp 1`

Comment: The documentation you linked in your post suggests to run CMake as `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch ..`. Did you follow that suggestion?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes ,i did. I edited the message, it says above

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. The **error** `By not providing "FindTorch.cmake" ... ` is emitted by CMake when you run it without `--build` argument. But according to your first output, that running has been **successful** (`Generating done`), and Torch library has been found: `Found Torch: C:/Packages/libtorch/lib/torch.lib`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I just follow the instructions. I click to the button generate. how can I start cmake with argument --build? I am sorry ,my knowledges are very small , I have just started

Comment: "I click to the button generate." - **Where** did you find that button? In CMake GUI? Or in Visual Studio? It looks like you perform your **own steps**, not the ones listed in the documentation. By itself, this is not bad. But for being able to help you we need to know which exact steps you have performed. Please, include your **actual** steps into the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is a very foolish question , but how can i add the picture to my comments. Stackoverflow server error

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it is a button in visual studio c++ intellisense information may be out of date,generate the Cmake cache to refresh and the buttons generate and settings

Comment: So you are using GUI for configure your project. In that GUI you need to set variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the appropriate value.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but how can i do it on visual studio ? and why it doesn't work?

Comment: "how can i do it on visual studio" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/customize-cmake-settings?view=msvc-170#command-arguments. "why it doesn't work?" - If you don't specify `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, then CMake cannot find  your Torch installation. This is written in the error message you got.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  I understand it. but ,I think , after the command cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=... , it must work,isn't it?

Comment: It must work.. assuming you are correctly building the configured project. But it is **not clear** what you are **actually** doing. The only thing you tell us is that your press "Generate" button in Visual Studio. Again, please update your **question post** (not comments!) with information about your actual steps.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added the picture of cmake button.After that I wrote all command in terminal i tried to build project , but after I started it gave the error that I sent

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think it is important to say that I cant build the project in visual studio and vs code. firstly I tried to install pytorch in vs code, but after a lot of attemps was failed, I went to visual studio

Comment: "After that I wrote all command in terminal i tried to build project" - Your commands in the terminal doesn't affect the configuring and building the project via GUI in Visual Studio. E.g. the fact that you set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in the terminal doesn't affect the configuration via GUI.

Comment: As for the updating the question post, adding a picrure doesn't make it clearer. In opposite, the picture shows that you are working in Visual Studio GUI, but the referenced instruction is about command line. Please, make your question post **clear** even for one, who **doesn't read comments**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think it must found the way to library if i set it in terminal,isn't it?How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added the command set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:\Packages\libtorch),but i still can't use pytorch outside the file. I tried to #include <torch> in other project visual studio it printed this:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'torch': No such file or directory Project1 C:\Users\Acer\C++ projects\fraimworks\Project1\main.cpp 1